# sed to match first pattern among multiple matches

Tags: sed, non-greedy

So for a given text like

> a[test] asdfasdf [sdfsdf]b

I want the first match of text which is inside the first square brackets (regex = [.*]), so in this case `[test]`.

I tried the following command it didn't work:

```
echo "a[test] asdfasdf [sdfsdf]b" | sed -n -e 's/.*\(\[.*\]\).*/\1/p'
```

This is returning `[sdfsdf]`

How do I get `[test]` instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` will select the longest match. Use `[^[]*` and `[^]]*` instead.

```
sed -n -e 's/[^[]*\(\[[^]]*\]\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: @Ram Gaddam: As an alternative: With Perl `.*?` will select the shortest match: `perl -p -e 's/.*?\[(.*?)\].*/\1/'`